# Using join() on dictionary in python to return key value pairs as one long string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, dictionary

I want to `join()` key and value pairs in a my dictionary with a `:` inbetween. I want to return it all as one string.

Intuitivly I hoped just plugging the dictionary in would work:

```
def format_grades(grades):


    return ': '.join(grades) + "\n"
```

I tried something like this `': '.join(str(n) for n in grades[n])` to convert my values to strings since my dict looks like this: `{john: 2}` but I can't think straight now, ideas?

Comment: How does your grades dictionary look like?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh key value pairs look like this; {kumar : 69}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using f-strings in python3 - you can iterate over the items in the dict and print each on a new line.

```
print("\n".join(f'{k}: {v}' for k,v in grades.items()))
```

Example:

```
grades = {'john': 2, 'marry': 4}
print("\n".join(f'{k}: {v}' for k,v in grades.items()))
```

Output:

```
john: 2
marry: 4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over the keys and values, and make the string by joining them

```
grades = {'Joe':'A','John':'B'}
print(" ".join('{}: {}'.format(k,v) for k,v in grades.items()))
#Joe: A John: B
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def format_grades(grades):

return ( "\n".join([str(i[0])+":"+str(i[1]) for i in grades.items()]) )
```